# Java comparing string to regex - while loop

Tags: java, regex, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I want the user to enter a string and if the string does not match my regex expression then I want a message to be outputted and the user to enter a value again.

The problem is even when the string matches the regex it is treating it as if it does not match.

My regex:
This should equal - `Name, Name`

`[[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*,\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*]`

My `while` loop:

```
  System.out.println("Enter the student's name in the following format - surname, forename: ");  studentName = input.next();
  while (!studentName.equals("[[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*,\\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*]")) {
    System.out.println("try again");
    studentName = input.next();
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `equals` methods checks for string equivalence, not for matching regular expressions.

Just replace `equals` with `matches`. You should also remove the outer square brackets.

Comment: When I do that it matches the wrong way round. i.e. if it's in the format I want it reports an error. If I remove the `!` in front `!studentName.equals` it reports an error when it does match the regex

Comment: I have `while (!studentName.matches("[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*,\\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*"))` but when I try `Name, Name` it prints `Try Again` twice

Comment: Probably `Name, Name` are to separate strings in your input. Try adding the wrong input in the message you print.

Comment: Looks like you're right, it's printing `Name, try again
Name try again` How can I fix this?

Comment: We can only help you if you provide us some more infos about your input,

Comment: What is `input` ? Which class ? Where do the values come from ?

Comment: `Input` is using `scanner`, The user is prompted to enter a name which is then entered into a array. `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: Scanner is splitting if a whitespace appears in the user input. Just print out the user input after you assigned it to studentName the first time and you will see it for yourself.

Comment: The `Scanner` javadoc says: `A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace`

Comment: Like phlogratos mentioned, change the delimiter using input.useDelimiter(); and it will work

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that your regexp is wrong?

```
test.matches("[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*,\\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*")
```

works fine for me.